# R - using a data frame as a "hash map"

Tags: r

I have a data frame with mappings of IDs to factors.

```
frame1:

ID grade
1  A
2  B
3  C
```

I want to use these mappings to add another column with grades in a different data frame which also contains an ID column

```
frame2:

ID NAME
1  x
2  y
1  x
```

I know how to do it using a for loop:

```
for(i in frame2$ID){
frame1 %>% filter(ID == i) %>%  select(grade)}
```

But I was wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: Use a named vector. Or merge (probably better in your case). Not sure what your loop is doing, though, it appears it does exactly nothing.

Comment: The for loop is used to extract grades based on IDs from frame1. It's a terrible solution, and named vectors or merge seem like a good idea. Thanks for the answer.